# Traefik docker-compose path based routing

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I have two services in a docker containers and I'm using Traefik as a reverse proxy to route requests between the two services. I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  
  api: 
    image: 'juliandimitrov/api-image:latest'
    container_name: 'api'
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=HostRegexp(`my-site.com/api`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.api-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/api"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=myapp-stripprefix@docker"
      - "traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

  web:
    image: 'juliandimitrov/web-image:latest'
    container_name: 'web'
    expose:
      - "80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # - "traefik.http.routers.web.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.rule=Host(`my-site.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.web.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

  proxy:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: "proxy"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

If I go to my browser and type `http://my-site.com` it routes the request to the `web` service. Then I try `http://my-site.com/api/users/authenticate` it routes it again in the `web` service, but I want all the requests that are `/api` to be routed to the `api` service.

How can I achieve that, because obviously my docker-compose configuration is not right.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question: why proxy service need a binded mount for the socket?

Comment: I think this is because this service has to have access to the `labels` information for the other services in order to configure them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of digging and trial and errors I managed it working with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  
  api: 
    image: 'juliandimitrov/api-image:latest'
    container_name: 'api'
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`my-site.com/api`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=strip-prefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.strip-prefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/api"
      - "traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

  web:
    image: 'juliandimitrov/web-image:latest'
    container_name: 'web'
    expose:
      - "80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.rule=Host(`my-site.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.web.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

  proxy:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: "proxy"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

Basicly the problem was in the `strip-perfix` middleware.

Comment: Question: could you explain the 'expose' entry for the 2 webservices? What happen if you do not add them?

Comment: I guess it will work again, this is leftover from the example file I used to create this one.